# kgpg decrypt files without asking paraphrase

Tags: kubuntu, gnupg

I have my own personal key pair. I encrypted folder in dolphin, using kgpg. (right click >encrypt) Then message came saying, it will create temp zip file in /tmp and it will delete that, after encrypting. And window came to ask me to choose which key to use to encrypt. I choose my own public key. They it created gpg file. Then I opened it by clicking on it. kgpg asked my pass phrase. So, I provided it and, it created decrypted file.

So, I copied encrypted file to another folder. And then I opened it again. (I did that to make sure I can decrypt that file using my pass phrase. That time it didn't ask me for pass phrase. It just decrypted it.

So I opended kgpg editor and typed 123 and clicked encrypt button. And then clicked decrypt button. It didn't asked for pass phrase. It decrypted that encrypted message correctly.

So, what is going on?
How can I make this stop and set it to ask pass phrase everytime?

I'm using Kubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my computer and, Then first time it asked me to enter password. But second time onwards it didn't ask me. So, I opened /tmp (as normal user) and saw gpg-agetXXXXXXX named folder. (X means don't remember) So, I deleted it. And now it works fine. Everytime it ask me to enter pass. I don't know is this a bug or not. But if this is a but, then kgpg (and or gnupg) has serious bug..